# Zend Framework 2 - How to set form validation rules for an entity using annotations?

Tags: php, validation, doctrine-orm, annotations, zend-framework2

How to set @Annotation\Validator for email address to make sure it is unique.

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", unique=true, length=255, nullable=false)
 * @Annotation\Type("Zend\Form\Element\Email")
 * @Annotation\Validator({"name":"EmailAddress", "options": {"unique":"true"}})
 * @Annotation\ErrorMessage("Invalid Email Address")
 * @Annotation\Attributes({"placeholder":"Your Email Address"})
 * @Annotation\Options({"label":"Your email address:"})
 */
public $email;
```

It does validate email and displays error message if email has wrong format or invalid characters but if email is duplicate then i get following error:

```
Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException

File:
doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/DBALException.php:91
Message:
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO subscriber (email, token, active) VALUES (?, ?, ?)' with params ["me@example.com", {}, 1]:

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'me@example.com' for key 'email'
```

Comment: Hello. You should let us know what you have tried. It will make it easier to help you then.

Answer (score 0):

By using @uniqueConstraint, see here:

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-uniqueconstraint

Comment: As i've understood from Doctrine documentation @uniqueConstraint only has meaning in the SchemaTool schema generation context
and it does work this way or the way it was done before using '@ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", unique=true ...'

What i'm trying to accomplish is to add validation rule using @Annotation\Validator so no attempt to save entity will be performed unless email is unique as it's done for example for string length @Annotation\Validator({"name":"StringLength", "options":{"min":"2","max="255"}})

Comment: Did you try the NoRecordExists validator?
https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Validator/Db/NoRecordExists.php

Comment: Direction seams right. I've used DoctrineModule\Validator\NoObjectExists while creating form manually. But problem comes with NoRecordExists that it can't find DB adapter same way as NoObjectExists is missing entity manager and i don't know if it's possible to specify it as annotation option

@Annotation\Validator({"name":"DoctrineModule\Validator\NoObjectExists", "options": {"fields"="email"}})

@Annotation\Validator({"name":"Zend\Validator\Db\NoRecordExists", "options": {"table"="subscriber", "field"="email"}})